# Adding objects to an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to add objects to an array.  What I'm trying to do specifically is, calculate how many items I can fit on a page, add those items to my itemsOnAPageArray, add that to my pagesArray, and then later use this info.  So my code is:

```
NSMutableArray *pagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *itemsOnAPage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [self.textObjects count]; i++) {
    TextObject *t = [self.textObjects objectAtIndex:i];

    width = MAX(width, t.size.width);

    // Fits on a page, add the object, update the size
    if (height + t.size.height < kReportPDFDefaultHeight) {
        [itemsOnAPage addObject:t];
        height += t.size.height;
    }
    // Doesn't fit on a page, add the items to the page
    else {

        [pagesArray addObject:itemsOnAPage];
        [pagesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"obj before: %@", [obj description]);
        }];

        [itemsOnAPage removeAllObjects];
        [pagesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"obj after: %@", [obj description]);
        }];
    }
}
```

However, when I start a new page, I want to clear the initial array and start adding objects to my 2nd page, and so forth.  But if I clear my array, then my pagesArray ends up being empty.  How can I go around this?  Thanks!

Comment: Well if you clear the array... there aren't going to be any items in it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a copy of your `itemsOnAPage` array when you insert it into the `pagesArray`, otherwise you'll end up with multiple copies of the last page:

```
        [pagesArray addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:itemsOnAPage]];
```

Comment: @dasblinenlight is arrayWithArray: the same as @[itemsOnAPage] with Xcode 4.4.1?

Comment: @Crystal I have no idea, the new cool syntax is not available for iOS development, so I am not using it yet. Supposedly, it is the same, but the easiest thing to find out would be to give it a try.